# How to override meta viewport of parent frame?

Tags: html, css, responsive, viewport, meta

I am creating content to sit within a frameset. I don't have access to the code that creates the frameset and it has a meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

The HTML content I'm creating has a fixed minimum width of 980px. When viewed within the frameset, it appears zoomed with this meta viewport tag. In my testing on a similar setup, removing this meta viewport tag allows my content to fit the viewport. However, as I can't remove this directly, can I add anything to the content I'm creating to override this parent meta viewport tag?

Comment: Ok, so I've managed to find a workaround that works in my test setup - just need to test on the live system 
`$(window.parent.document).find('head meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', '')`

Answer (score 0):

No.

The viewport mode for the top-level frame affects the entire viewport (i.e. all descendant frames).

Your best bet is to change the design so it is responsive instead of fixed width.